# How to avoid .git when search for a string using grep

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, git, grep

I am trying to make a search in a folder for a string using grep.

```
grep -r "word" .
```

But it is including a search in .git files which I would like to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot comment, but try using [`git-grep`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html), it's a nice and simple tool for this job. git grep --untracked "word"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to exclude `.git` directories:

```
grep --exclude-dir=".git" -r "word" .
```

This works on GNU `grep`, not on other versions, but since you seem to be using Linux, this should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

try 'ack' ( http://beyondgrep.com/ ), it ignores .git, .hg, .csv etc etc by itself:

> Searches entire trees by default while ignoring Subversion, Git and
>   other VCS directories and other files that aren't your source code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more flexible solution for the case if your `grep` doesn't support excluding dirs:

> find . -type d -path */.git -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -e grep word